# Android UI flickers on posting to handler

Tags: java, android, listview, bitmap, handler

In one of my adapters for a custom `ListView`, I have a piece of code to insert a `Bitmap` into an `ImageView` that looks something like this :

```
Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);   
    }
});
```

Except that I'm passing on the `Handler` along with a callback (that is later wrapped in the `Runnable`), to a different thread which computes the `Bitmap` to be displayed and then posts the results on to the provided `handler`.

And every time the `ListView` is updated, the contents flicker a couple of times.

I'm aware that `AsyncTask`s are primarily for this purpose. But I'd still like to know what is causing the screen to flicker.

Comment: Maybe you're changing that bitmap asynchronously while setting it to ImageView ? So one thread is writing to it and another one is reading concurrently ?

Comment: Not the code you posted. Flicker is probably something you accidentally do e.g. clear the image then a few milliseconds later set it again then clear it, and so on. Check (print to log) how often you call that handler code.

Comment: The code is being called multiple times frequently. Now if I cache the bitmap, and call the callback on the same thread (since there is no blocking operation) instead of using the handler, there is no flicker. And if I call the callback using the handler, the flicker happens again.

Comment: So I do not think that its because the list is being re-populated multiple times.